# Problemas al pasar función de JS Vanilla a JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código en JS para cambiar el color y el texto de un div, al hacer click en cada uno de los divs de mi paleta de color:

```
var indicadorColor = document.getElementById('indicador-de-color');
var indicadorMensaje = document.getElementById('indicador-de-color-mensaje');
var color = document.getElementsByClassName('color-paleta');

function mostrarColor(){
  indicadorColor.style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
  indicadorMensaje.innerText = 'PINCEL: ' + this.style.backgroundColor;
}

function seleccionarColor(){
  for(i=0; i<color.length; i++){
    color[i].addEventListener('click', mostrarColor)
  }
}

seleccionarColor();
```

Esto me funciona sin problemas, el tema es que lo quiero pasar a JQuery para ahorrar lineas de codigo y cuando pruebo con el siguiente codigo no me funciona:

```
    function seleccionarColor(){
        var color = $('.color-paleta');
            for(i=0; i<color.length; i++){
                $(color[i]).click(function() {
                 $('indicador-de-color').attr('background-color', $(color[i]).css('background-color'));
                 $('indicador-de-color-mensaje').text($(color[i]).css('background-color'))
            }
        )}
        }
        seleccionarColor();
})
```

No puedo ver el error :( Alguien me puede dar una mano? Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que te falta usar el indicador de id's `#`.  Intenta asi:

```
function seleccionarColor(){
    var color = $('.color-paleta');
        for(i=0; i<color.length; i++){
            $(color[i]).click(function() {
             $('#indicador-de-color').attr('background-color', $(color[i]).css('background-color'));
             $('#indicador-de-color-mensaje').text($(color[i]).css('background-color'))
        }
    )}
    }
    seleccionarColor();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de mas propiedades de jQuery, como agregar un listener y cambiar cada comoponente por `this`, ademas, cuando apuntas a un elemento por su Id, utiliza `#`

```
$(() => {
    $('.color-paleta').on('click', function() {
        $('#indicador-de-color').attr('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
        $('#indicador-de-color-mensaje').text($(this).css('background-color'));
    });
});
```